# Nodejs Runs Promise but still Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am facing a peculiar problem which I am unable to debug. TypeError: My code is returning function is undefined which ends the API call but I look at the log and break points, after the API ends with the error, it proceeds to the then function of the same.

How is this possible.

Am using nodejs/express/sequelizejs

```
models.Holdings.update(obj,{
      where:{
             id: obj.id
            }
}).then().catch()
```

Comment: Pass functions to then and catch.

Comment: @danh: How. I couldn't understand your point

Answer (score 2):

Then and catch are meant to provide functions to execute upon resolution and error (respectively).

```
models.Holdings.update(obj,{
      where:{
             id: obj.id
            }
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: True. But My issue is my code is going first to catch i.e error block and after that few seconds later is entering into the then block. This is wierd. If it has gone through the catch block, then how it can later go into then block.

Comment: I don't think it can.  But the OP code shows no blocks passed to either.  It can't be going to either then or catch code if that code doesn't exist